# integration by parts solution

Tags: integration

$$$$
I got $X\in L^\infty$ and $F$ a distribution of r.v. $X$.
The following equation I want to show: 
$$
\int\limits_{t}^\infty (x-t)dF_X(x)=\int\limits_{t}^\infty (1-F_X(x))dx
$$
I know from my teacher that I have to use the following rule:
$$
\int\limits_{a}^b f(x)dg(x)=f(x)g(x)|^b_a-\int\limits_{a}^b g(x)df(x)
$$
When I try it:
$$
f(x)=x-t, \qquad g(x)=F(x)
$$
Then I get:
$$
(x-t)F_X(x)|^\infty_t-\int\limits_{t}^\infty F_X(x)d(x-t)
$$
But now I do not know how to go on. If I enter $\infty$ then I get $\infty$ and not the desired equation.

Maybe someone can help me at this.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I recommend you to avoid using emojis on Math Stack Exchange.

Comment: Why? *suppressing to use a emoji*

Comment: The function $F_X(x)$ should have a finite value when $x\to \infty$. So further evaluation may be possible.

Comment: But I got $(x-t)F(x)$ So symbolically I get $(\infty-t)F(\infty)=(\infty-t)$.

Comment: @Keplox You didn't tell us this, but I suspect that $F$ is a distribution of r. v. $X$. Perhaps there are more assumptions about $F$?

Comment: Yes sorry. $F$ is distribution of r.v. $X$. Another assumption is $X\in L^\infty$. I do not know how this should help. I will add this information above thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is $M$ such that $|X|\leq M$ almost everywhere, because $X\in L^\infty$. Then for $t<M+1$ (because $F(x) = 1$ for $x\geq M+1$; I chose $M+1$ to make sure of this)
$$\int_t^\infty (x-t)\ dF(x) = \int_t^{M+1} (x-t)\ dF(x)+\int_{M+1}^\infty(x-t)\ d(1) = \int_t^{M+1} (x-t)\ dF(x) $$

$$\int_t^{M+1} (x-t)\ dF(x) = (x-t)F(x)\big |_{x = t}^{x = M+1} - \int_t^{M+1} F(x)\ dx $$

$$M+1-t-\int_t^{M+1}F(x)\ dx = \int_t^{M+1}(1-F(x))\ dx = \int_t^\infty (1-F(x))\ dx $$
If $t\geq M+1$, then it's even simpler because both sides are just $0$.